# Excel VBA: using replace for multiple selected cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am using vba to get combined value in an cell from selection range

what i wanna do is.. i give selection in sheet and run my vba code then in result i would get merged value in an another cell.

but instead of this i am getting value "TRUE"

** in my code i replace enter to comma & for enter i used chr(10).

code i am using is:

```
Sub abc()
Dim a As String
Dim b As String
a = Selection.Copy
b = Replace(a, Chr(10), ",")
ActiveCell.Offset(4, 0).Value = b
ActiveCell.Offset(4, 1).Value = a
End Sub
```

[image](http://i63.tinypic.com/153v2tz.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Sub abc()
    Dim a As String
    Dim b As String
    a = ActiveCell.Value
    b = Replace(a, Chr(10), ",")
    ActiveCell.Offset(4, 0).Value = b
    ActiveCell.Offset(4, 1).Value = a
End Sub
```

Comment: not working... just giving value of one cell that is in selection as this is copying only selection but i need to copy range of selection...